# How to read csv lines with pandas containing " and ' between quoting character "?

Tags: python, regex, csv, pandas, quoting

I'm trying to import csv with pandas read_csv and can't get the lines containing the following snippet to work:

> "","",""BSF" code  - Intermittant, see notes",""

I am able to get pass it via with the options `error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False, engine='c'`. However it should be possible to parse them correctly. I'm not good with regular expressions so I didn't try using `engine='python', sep=regex` yet. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try the usual [csv module](http://ideone.com/Tix0Ca)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's quite a hard one ... given that all fields are quoted you could use a regex to only use , followed and preceded by " as a separator:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=r'(?<="),(?=")',quotechar='"')
```

However, you will still end up with quotes around all fields, but you could fix this by applying

```
data = data.applymap(lambda s:s[1:-1])
```

Comment: I tried this out and it seemed to work, nice job. As each field is surrounded by quotes, you can use `","` as a delimiter, rather than `", or ,"`, correct? I tried replacing your regex with `sep=r'(?<="),(?=")'` and it seemed to work.

Comment: Also, to clarify as it wasn't immediately obvious to me, data.applymap doesn't change the data frame in place, it returns a new one, so one would need to use `data = data.applymap(...)` I believe.

Comment: @Ogaday, both of your remarks are correct. A comma is indeed always surrounded by two parantheses in this case and yes, applymap does not alter data in place. I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks!